# Would it be possible to create a Script that could search multiple sheets in a workbook for multiple inquries?

Tags: arrays, search, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am learning scripting and am fairly new to all of this. Right now I have a google workbook which consists of multiple sheets (Each sheet is a different month, "January 2020", "February 2020", etc..) and those sheets log calls that employees make. The Columns for those calls track, date of the calls, time of the calls, name of the employee making the call, name of the caller, reason for the calls, etc...

What I am wondering if I could write a script on one sheet where I could have multiple search criteria as well as set it to search between certain dates. Then when I activate the script (probably with a button), the rows below would display all rows contained the in sheets that contain the provided criteria. The thing would be making it so if a search field was left blank the script would not search for that info (For instance if caller's name was left blank) in stead of searching for rows that contained the provided information and a blank.

I have attached a picture of my idea that I hope would provide some clarification. [Example page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIPxQ.jpg)

Again, I am not even sure if this would be possible. Even though I am new to Scripting, just having to describe this makes me think it will probably be complicated.

Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: I did realize that I forgot to fill in the cells for "reason for call". If this were to work in that example the reasons would all be "Service renewal"

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but instead of changing the rows to display the result, it would be better to open a [modal dialog box](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui) when clicking on the button.

To do so, follow the steps:

1. Create an HTML file in your Project by clicking on `File > New > HTML File`
2. Use the code from the Class UI link I shared before, but using [createHtmlOutputFromFile](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service.html#createHtmlOutputFromFile(String)) instead:

```
function displayResults(){
    // Display a modal dialog box with custom HtmlService content.
    var htmlOutput = HtmlService
        .createHtmlOutputFromFile('Mypage')
        .setWidth(250)
        .setHeight(300);
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'My add-on');
}
```

3. In the HTML file, create a regular site with a table which you will populate with the data from the Sheet. Use [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) in the Javascript side to communicate the Dialog Box with Google Apps Script.
4. In the Sheet, assign a button to run the `displayResults` function.

You can find more information [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html#code.gs)

Comment: First of all, thank you for your input, I am looking at building the HTML page right now. Once I create the page am I going to by running a Script that would display a Vlookup type results or something like a MATCH / INDEX search? or is there a different Function that I am not thinking about?

Comment: You don't need Formulas for this case. Create a function in Apps Script which returns [the cells values](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues()) and call it from the HTML file with a [succesHandler](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html_2). It will return a 2D array which you can use to populate an HTML table.